# Proving something is a normed space

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Define a function $\| \cdot \| \colon \mathbb{C^3}  \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$\|(z_1, z_2, z_3)\| = |z_1| + |z_2| + |z_3|$$

Show that this is a norm on $\mathbb{C^3}$.

Not really sure how to begin this let alone conduct a full proof, I know a norm $\|\cdot\|$

1. Is positive definite: $\|\textbf{u}\| \geq 0$ and $\|\textbf{u}\| = 0$ iff $\textbf{u} = 0;$
2. Is positive homogeneous: $\|\lambda \textbf{u}\| = |\lambda|\ \|\textbf{u}\|;$
3. Satisfies the triangle inequality: $\|\textbf{u} + \textbf{v}\| \le \|\textbf{u}\| + \|\textbf{v}\|$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Begin at the beginning.  Can you show that no matter what $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are, we have $|z_1| + |z_2| + |z_3| \ge 0$?  Can you show that if $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are three numbers such that $|z_1| + |z_2| + |z_3| = 0$, then they must all be zero?

Comment: Hint: first prove that $|\cdot|$ is a norm on $\mathbb C$. Then. prove that if you have some norm $l$ on $\mathbb R^k$, then $l' : \mathbb R^{kr} \to \mathbb R, (x_1, \dots, x_r) \to l(x_1) + \dots + l(x_r)$ is a norm. (verify triangle inequality, as other properties are automatical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full worked out solution, just so you can see it and be able to work out similar problems in full detail by yourself in the future.

Let $\omega\in \mathbb{C}^3$, with $\omega=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$. Here we have just defined what a vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$ is.

Now we are trying to see if $||\cdot ||:\mathbb{C^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as defined by $||\omega||=|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|$ satisfies the requirement for being a norm. All we have to do to show something is a norm is just work through each requirement one at a time (or more if you are slick).

$1$. Note we certainly have positive definiteness. We know that $|z_1|, |z_2|, |z_3|$ are all individually positive, so their sum must be positive. The only way to have $||\omega||=0$ is if all three components were zero. The converse, namely if $||\omega||=0$, then $\omega$ itself is zero. This one is obvious.

$2$. Note we can write $||\lambda \omega||=|\lambda|(|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|)$ which certainly holds, as we can distribute $\lambda$ to each component.

$3$. The triangle inequality is also satisfied. Now let $u\in \mathbb{C^3}$ be another vector with $u=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$. We can set up our inequality $||u+\omega||\leq ||u||+||\omega||$, which yields

$(|\alpha_1+z_1|+|\alpha_2+z_2|+|\alpha_3+z_3|)\leq (|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|)+(|\alpha_1|+|\alpha_2|+|\alpha_3|)$

Note that $|\alpha_1+z_1|\leq |\alpha_1|+|z_1|$ by Triangle Inequality for two arbitrary numbers. Apply the exact same logic to second and third components and put them together to prove the *norm* satisfies the Triangle Inequality. Since all three axioms hold, the norm is indeed a norm and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You "only" have to explicitly show that the map $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ have the properties you listed. You have the advantage to know that these properties are true for $|\cdot|$, which is a norm on $\mathbb{C}$ and also a main constituent of the definition of $\Vert\cdot\Vert$. For example, about positive def.: we should prove that $\Vert (x,y,z)\Vert \geq0$, but $$\Vert(x,y,z)\Vert=|x|+|y|+|z|$$is the sum of non negative terms, then the thesis. Further, $\Vert (x,y,z)\Vert=0$ means that a sum of non negative terms is zero; this is true if and only if they are all zero (as numbers), that is $(x,y,z)=\boldsymbol{0}\in\mathbb{C}^3$ since $|z|=0\Leftrightarrow z=0\in\mathbb{C}$. 
The other properties are similar, try to work them out by yourself.